# Javascript: is using t_this inside anonymous functions considered harmful?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using:

```
var t_this = this; // Used inside anonymous functions
```

for quite some time when dealing with anonymous functions inside a 'class' but always with unease as it looks like a code smell. Is this a bad practice? Is there a better alternative?

example:

```
$("#container").click(function() {
    t_this.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Something you see in code which makes you think there might be a problem. I think Kent Beck (Mr. XP) came up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than maybe picking a better name, this practice is recommended in lots of situations, and works as a caching mechanism by reducing calls to object lookups outside the current scope. Recommended for more than just `this`.

For example, if you have an object outside of the current scope like:

```
var Application = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: {}
        }
    }
};
```

You will want to cache that to reduce processing from traversing the object. Instead of:

```
Application.a.b.c.doSomething();

// later

Application.a.b.c.doSomething();
```

Cache it, much quicker:

```
var c = Application.a.b.c;

c.doSomething();

// later

c.doSomething();
```

In this way, c is only looked up once, as opposed to multiple times.

Comment: Can you give examples of why it reduces calls for lookups?

Comment: Obviously this is negligible, but its the principal that applies. When you are dealing with large data structures or mission critical applications, negligible adds up.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common practice; there's nothing wrong with it.

However, underscores are not usually used in Javascript identifiers; I would name the variable `me` or `self` (or even `that`)

Answer (score 2):

Not at all, though I usually call it `$this` (if it's a proper jQuery object) or `that`, unless I can give it a more descriptive name.

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard way to reference the value of `this` in an outer scope. Consider, for example:

```
function output() {
    var t_this = this;
    $("#container").click(function() {
        t_this.doSomething();
    });
}
```

The value of `this` inside the `click` handler will not be the same as the value of `this` in the outer function. Assigning its value to another variable is exactly the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

```
$("#container").click($.proxy( 
    function() { this.doSomething(); },
    this // you can use any variable here, and it will be called 'this' inside the function
));
```

This way you pass the context to the inside scope. Not saying it's better, but maybe it smell better for you. I prefer this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, why you need to alias *this* instead of using it? I only alias *this* when I have another nested anonymous function with a different caller. for example:

```
    $('#container').click(function() {
        // this refer to #container
        this.doThis();

        // alias this
        objPointer = this;

        // call a function on different objects
        $('div.class').click(function(){
            // this now refer to div.class
            this.doElse()

            // objPointer refer to #container
            objPointer.doThis()
        });
    });
```

Comment: That's exactly why he is aliasing.